# Network Based Kernel Density estimation Guiding Module for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, kernel-density, arcgis-10.5

I need a guidance module for performing Network Based Kernel Density Estimation in ArcGIS 10.5. When I was going through several answers here, I saw [Nearest Neighbor Analysis for route events](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/189567/115) about an analyst tool SANET which is compatible with ArcGIS Version 10 or less than that.

Is there any other Addon can anyone suggest to perform it in ArcGIS 10.5?

Answer (score 0):

[SANET](http://sanet.csis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/) is compatible to at least ArcGIS 10.2.

[image]

I recommend trying it at your version, and if it does not work, then contact its authors to see if they plan to release a version that does.

Comment: Just tried this with 10.6. Unfortunately the download only starts if you have 10.2 installed. Otherwise the toolbox installer pops up with an error message. Hoepfully someone finds another solution, I am having this same issue 2 years later